# Should useCallback() be used on a function passed as a prop to a child component even if said component is wrapped in a memo()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memo

in React, when a component re-renders, all the functions inside that component will be recreated, resulting in a change in function references.

So that even if a child component is wrapped in memo() to prevent it from unnessecary rerenders caused by parent component. It would still rerender in case a function is passed to it as a prop from the parent component?

Here is an example:

```
const Parent = () => { 
  const [state, setState] = useState("1"); 
 
  const handleIncrement = useCallback(() => { 
    const increment = setState(state + 1);  
  }, [state]);
 
  return (  
    <Child handle={() => handleIncrement()} /> 
  );
}

const Child = memo(({handle}) => {
  return();
});
```

That's the main purpose of using useCallback() on functions passed to the child component? so that the function's reference will stay the same between rerenders that don't affect the usecallback dependency array for that function in the parent component. Which passes the reference equality check done by the child component?

Resulting in maintaining the same function reference when a function is passed as a prop to a child component? preventing rerenders from making the use of memo() uneffective?

My question: is that the most important use of usecallback(), generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "component" is simply a JavaScript function.
"Rendering" a component simply means "running the function".

You are correct that each time a JS function runs it recreates the variables within it, including function definitions.

The "magic" that React offers to avoid things looking like they are being recreated is `useState()`, `useMemo()`, `useCallback()`, etc.  These are in no way bypassing the base JS behaviours mentioned above.  These hooks "cache" values when they are first run, and subsequent runs (i.e. subsequent "renders"), if React sees that it has a variable/object/function in cache then it gives that value back to the "new" instance create by useState/useMemo/useFunction as was in the previous run.

Now, in your above example if the `handle` property changes then it will regenerate the Child component and so it will be re-rendered.  You have at least 2 ways to avoid this:

1. use `useCallback()` when defining `handleIncrement()` (as you have done....but see below)
2. pass a second parameter to `memo()` -- a function that is meant to compare previous and current props to the component and return `true` if they are the same (i.e. do not render).  So you could simply set that second parameter to `() => true` and it will never re-generate and never re-render.

Now ...as for your current `handleIncrement()`.  You have it using a `useCallback()` that is dependent on the value of `state`.  But each time that `handleIncrement()` is called, it is increasing the value of `state`.  So that will cause `Parent` to re-render and with the new value of `state` useCallback() will re-generate `handleIncrement()` as a new function because its dependency has a new value.

And....one last thing: `setState(state + 1);` is a TERRIBLE pattern to code to.  Because `setState()` is an asynchronous function, you are telling React (well, JavaScript):  "at some point later in time, please take the current value of `state`, add `1` to it, and put it back into `state`".

The problem here is that if `setState()` gets called multiple times before JavaScript gets around to running its asynchronous queue....you can end up losing data!!!!  If the current value of `state` is `7` and you code:

```js
setState(state + 1);
setState(state + 100);
setState(state - 2);
```

then when your component finally gets around to re-rendering the value of `state` will be `5`...because JS was told to run `7 + 1` and `7 + 100` and `7 - 2`...and the last one wins.

Whenever you have a state variable and you want to update its value to be relative to its current value -- whether that be an array, an object, a string, an integer, whatever -- then you want to use the "callback signature" of the "set state function":  `setState(currVal => currVal + 1)`.

This syntax tells JavaScript "at the timet that you are running the set state function, get its current value, add `1`, then put it back into the state variable".

With this latter approach, if you call `setState()` a thousand times, it will get the correct answer every single time.  Given the same conditions above, `state` is `7` and you code:

```js
setState(currVal => currVal + 1);
setState(currVal => currVal + 100);
setState(currVal => currVal - 2);
```

then JS will do: `7 + 1` and `8 + 100` and `108 - 2`.  The value on re-render will be `106`.  The main difference is that `setState(currVal => ....)` gets the value of the state variable ***at the time that `setState()` is running***, whereas `setState(state + 1)` gets the value of `state` ***at the time `setState()` is being added to the asynchronous queue.

If you haven't already, I strongly encourage all of my friends (and make it a requirement of all of my coworkers) to watch the video [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s) multiple times, especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).

Comment: This was such a thorough and easy to understand answer, It helped me further understands the stuff that I had in mind. The additional memo() advice alongside the BETTER setstate() pattern were truly helpful as well. Thank you

Comment: I added a bit more to the setState() description with some examples and added a link to a video about asynchronous code invocation.

Comment: Alright THAT last additional part at the end "The main difference is..." is what made it all click together. Very much appreciated! thanks for providing such additional insights to the inner workings of  the "callback signature", would have slipped my mind otherwise.
Again! thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: The video is worth watching a bazillion times....at least the parts about asynchronous execution.  JS is non-intuitive on this front.

Comment: I could tell that my knowledge on javascript is a bit lacking, and that I should shore up on that part instead of jumping to react. Planning to dedicat the entire day of  tomorrow (or even more days) to watching that video.