# React component doesnt update when updating from different component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mui-x-data-grid

So I am creating a webapp where I am using Material-UI DataGrid. Expense.js below is the main page I am trying to render. Inside it, I have used three different components. The Custom Data Grid component, the Loading component, and a Custom Upload Button which I am rendering inside each DataGrid row in a column.

Now the Upload Button uploads a file to Drive and tries to add its URL to another column. I fetch the data initially to fill the Datagrid from the server. If I click on the Upload Button for the prefetched data, it works well. It sets the URL to another column.

If I add a row dynamically on the UI and then try to upload a file, it doesn't set the URL in the other column. I can see API request succeeding and rows being updated. But it doesn't show up on the UI.

Strange part is, if I don't split these components into three separate components and add everything inside the main Expense component as nested components, it all works well. The code below is a bit lengthy, I have tried to keep it readable.

Expense.js

```
    const [snackbar, setSnackbar] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = useState({});
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 50 },
        { field: 'projectId', type: 'number', headerName: 'Project ID', width: 150, editable: true },
        { field: 'dueId', headerName: 'Due ID', width: 150 },
        { field: 'description', headerName: 'Description', width: 150, editable: true },
        {
            field: 'expenseDate', type: 'date', headerName: 'Expense Date', width: 150, editable: true, valueGetter: (params) => {
                return new Date(params.value)
            }
        },
        { field: 'amount', type: 'number', headerName: 'Amount', width: 150, editable: true },
        {
            field: 'document', headerName: 'Document Link', width: 150,
            // renderCell: renderLink, 
            editable: true,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Upload Document', width: 150,
            renderCell: (params) => <UploadButton params={params} ------> UPLOAD BUTTON COMPONENT
                setRows={setRows} rows={rows} setLoading={setLoading} setRowModesModel={setRowModesModel} />,
        },
        { field: 'approved', type: 'boolean', headerName: 'Approved', width: 150, editable: true },
        { field: 'reimburesed', type: 'boolean', headerName: 'Reimbursed', width: 150, editable: true },
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading && (<Loading />)}
            <DataGridCustom
                customColumns={columns}
                getUrl={EXPENSE_LIST_URI}
                createUrl={CREATE_EXPENSE_URI}
                updateUrl={UPDATE_EXPENSE_URI}
                rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
                setRowModesModel={setRowModesModel}
                setLoading={setLoading}
                setSnackbar={setSnackbar}
                rows={rows}
                setRows={setRows} />
            {!!snackbar && (
                <SnackBarCustom snackbar={snackbar} setSnackbar={setSnackbar} />
            )}
        </div>
    );

}
```

Upload_Button.js

```
const VisuallyHiddenInput = styled('input')({
    clip: 'rect(0 0 0 0)',
    clipPath: 'inset(50%)',
    height: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: 1,
});

export default function UploadButton({params, setLoading, setRowModesModel, setRows, rows}) {
    const { userName, userEmail, userRole } = useContext(UserContext)

    function handleChange(event) {
        setLoading(true)
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOST + USER_GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI
        request.open("GET", url, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.send();
        const res = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const formData = new FormData();
        const metadata = {
            name: userEmail + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.name,
            mimeType: file.type,
            parents: [EXPENSES_FOLDER_ID],
            response: 'file.id'
        }
        formData.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {
            type: "application/json"
        }))
        formData.append("file", file)

        fetch(GOOGLE_DRIVE_UPLOAD_FILE_URI, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res.accessToken }),
            body: formData
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function (val) {
            const fileUrl = DRIVE_FILE_URI + val.id
            console.log("Params")
            console.log(params)
            setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
                ...oldModel,
                [params.id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'document' },
            }));
            setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === params.id ? {...row, document: fileUrl} : row))); ----------> Setting Row here
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }


    return (
        <Button size="small" component="label" variant="contained" startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}>
            Upload file
            <VisuallyHiddenInput type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
        </Button>
    );
```

Custom_Data_Grid.js

```
export default function DataGridCustom({ customColumns, customPermissions, getUrl,
    createUrl, updateUrl, rowModesModel, setRowModesModel, setLoading, setSnackbar, rows, setRows }) {


    console.log("rendering data grid")
    console.log("rows")
    console.log(rows)
    function guidGenerator() {
        var S4 = function () {
            return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
        };
        return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4());
    }

    const { userName, userEmail, userRole } = useContext(UserContext)

    function checkPermission(action) {
        return customPermissions[action] === "admin" ? true : false
    }

    console.log({ customColumns })
    const columns = [
        ...customColumns,
        {
            field: 'actions',
            type: 'actions',
            headerName: 'Actions',
            width: 100,
            cellClassName: 'actions',
            getActions: ({ id }) => {
                const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

                if (isInEditMode) {
                    return [
                        <GridActionsCellItem
                            icon={<SaveIcon />}
                            label="Save"
                            sx={{
                                color: 'primary.main',
                            }}
                            onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
                            disabled={userRole !== "admin"}
                        />,
                        <GridActionsCellItem
                            icon={<CancelIcon />}
                            label="Cancel"
                            className="textPrimary"
                            onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
                            color="inherit"
                            disabled={userRole !== "admin"}
                        />,
                    ];
                }

                return [
                    <GridActionsCellItem
                        icon={<EditIcon />}
                        label="Edit"
                        className="textPrimary"
                        onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
                        color="inherit"
                        disabled={userRole !== "admin"}
                    />,
                    <GridActionsCellItem
                        icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                        label="Delete"
                        onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
                        color="inherit"
                        disabled
                    />,
                ];

            },
        },
    ];
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOST + getUrl, {
            credentials: "include"
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setRows(data);
                setLoading(false);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
                handleProcessRowUpdateError(error)
            });
    }, []);

    const makeRequest = (data) => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (data.isNew) {
            const url = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOST + createUrl
            request.open("POST", url, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
            delete data.id;
        }
        else {
            const url = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_HOST + updateUrl
            request.open("PUT", url, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
        }
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        delete data.isNew;
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        return JSON.parse(request.responseText)
    }

    function AddToolbar(props) {
        const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

        const handleClick = () => {
            const id = guidGenerator()
            setRows((oldRows) => [...oldRows, { id, isNew: true }]);
            setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
                ...oldModel,
                [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'name' },
            }));
        };

        return (
            <GridToolbarContainer>
                <Button color="primary" startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick} disabled={userRole === "user"}>
                    Add Record
                </Button>
            </GridToolbarContainer>
        );
    }


    const handleRowEditStop = (params, event) => {
        if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
            event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
        }
    };

    const handleEditClick = (id) => () => {
        setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
    };

    const handleSaveClick = (id) => () => {
        setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
    };

    const handleDeleteClick = (id) => () => {
        setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    };

    const handleCancelClick = (id) => () => {
        setRowModesModel({
            ...rowModesModel,
            [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
        });

        const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
        if (editedRow.isNew) {
            setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
        }
    };

    const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
        setLoading(true)
        console.log("New Row")
        console.log(newRow)
        const oldId = newRow.id
        const savedRow = makeRequest(newRow);
        setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === oldId ? savedRow : row)));
        setLoading(false)
        return savedRow;
    };

    const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel) => {
        setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
    };
    const handleProcessRowUpdateError = useCallback((error) => {
        setLoading(false)
        setSnackbar({ children: error.message, severity: 'error' });
    }, []);

    return (

        <div>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    height: 500,
                    width: '100%',
                    '& .actions': {
                        color: 'text.secondary',
                    },
                    '& .textPrimary': {
                        color: 'text.primary',
                    },
                }}
            >
                <DataGrid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                    editMode="row"
                    rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
                    onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
                    onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
                    processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
                    onProcessRowUpdateError={handleProcessRowUpdateError}
                    slots={{
                        toolbar: AddToolbar,
                    }}
                    slotProps={{
                        toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
                    }}
                />
            </Box>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: One issue with your code to watch out for is your line `setRows(rows.map(........))`.  This is a VERY BAD PATTERN.  When you want to update a state variable to a value based on its existing value, use the form: `setRows(currVal => currVal.map(......))`  This likely won't resolve the issue, but this could become a deep seated bug down the road.

Comment: Why use XMLHttpRequest() when you are already using fetch() elsewhere?

Comment: You have this `setRows(rows.map(......))` pattern in several places.  The more you have it, the higher the likelihood of hitting the "asynch-hole" bug.  Again, I encourage you to move to the `setRows(oldRows => oldRows.map(.....))` pattern to avoid the asynch-hole issue.

Comment: @GregFenton can you explain more about this. Sorry, I am new to Javascript and Frontend development

Comment: Maybe this answer I gave yesterday will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77602978/229326

Comment: @GregFenton Thankyou. And what's wrong with XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with XMLHttpRequest, except that it is the first generation of server communication technology, so it is older and cruftier.  The fact that it "could be synchronous or asynchronous" with a non-obvious tweak of code is scary, especially when code is being maintained by different players over time.  `fetch()`, `axios()` and others have come along bringing newer and more obvious approaches to web communications.